# Solution to nonhomogeneous systems

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm not quite sure about finding a solution to nonhomogeneous systems theoretically.

If I have a M x N system, M equations and N variables, and I I represent that in matrix A : M x N , and I write the column of the solutions B in the matrix too.

First of all I need to find out if the system is consistent(=there is some solution to the system of equations) or inconsistent.
I've learned that: if and only if Rank(A)= m , then it is consistent.

I don't understand why it is "if and only if" statement  since if for exmaple the matrix is 3 x 3 and the last row of the matrix, and the column of the solutions gets all zeros, so it still can be consistent with infinite solutions..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly, but for systems of linear equations, consistency means the existence of a solution. An inconsistent system is one from which you arrive at contradictions like 1=0 (one without solutions). You can have consistent systems of equations with infinitely many solutions, which are ones that give rise to tautologies (like 1=1) when being solved.
Here's an example:

$x+y=1$

$2x+3y=2+y$

Any pair of the form $(x,1-x)$ solves the system and it is consistent.